# How to download a file without displaying directory selection UI when calling StorageAccessFramework in expo-file-system

Tags: android, react-native, expo, storage-access-framework, expo-file-system

I'm making a function to save a file downloaded from a server via `expo-file-system`.
In this code, when you click the download button on Android, the file selection UI appears, and when you select a file, the file is downloaded. However, I want files to be automatically downloaded in a specific directory without user selection, like a normal application.

When using `requestDirectoryPermissionAsync`, is it possible to directly download a file to a specific path without SelectionUI? If `StorageAccessFramework` doesn't have such a way, is there a way to solve this problem in `expo-file-system`?

**code**

```
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";

const { StorageAccessFramework } = FileSystem;

const saveAndroidFile = async (fileUri, fileName, contentType) => {
    try {
        const fileDir = StorageAccessFramework.getUriForDirectoryInRoot("Download");

        // This function calls the UI in the image below
        const permissions = await StorageAccessFramework.requestDirectoryPermissionsAsync(fileDir);
        if (!permissions.granted) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            await StorageAccessFramework.createFileAsync(fileDir, fileName, contentType)
                .then(async (uri) => {
                    await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(uri, fileString, { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64 });
                    alert("Report Downloaded Successfully");
                })
                .catch((e) => {
                    console.log(e);
                });
        } catch (e) {
            throw new Error(e);
        }
    } catch (err) {}
};
```

**Folder SelectionUI, which opens whenever `requestDirectoryPermissionAsync` is called**
[image]

Comment: `the file selection UI appears` Which file should be selected? Choose the file that will be downloaded?

Comment: And where is that download button on Android?

Comment: Take the photo above as an example. Now, when you touch the download button, the SelectionUI as above appears. What I want is to create a new directory in the **Documents** directory and download the file in it without the UI popping up.

Comment: There are various file types to download, such as pdf, img, and mp4.

Comment: You did not answer my questions. Not one.